# Replace keys with values and write in a new file Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I've got a problem trying to replace keys (dictionary) that I have in a file, with its corresponding values. More details: an input file called `event_from_picks` looks like:

```
EVENT2593
EVENT2594
EVENT2595

EVENT41025
EVENT2646
EVENT2649
```

Also, my dictionary, created by `reloc_event_coords_dic()` looks like:

```
{'EVENT23595': ['36.9828   -34.0538   138.1554'], 'EVENT2594': ['41.2669   -33.0179   139.2269'], 'EVENT2595': ['4.7500   -32.7926   138.1523'], 'EVENT41025': ['16.2453   -32.9552   138.2604'], 'EVENT2646': ['5.5949   -32.4923   138.1866'], 'EVENT2649': ['7.9533   -31.8304   138.6966']}
```

What I'd like to end up with, is a new file with the values instead of the keys. In this case, a new file called receiver.in which will look like:

```
36.9828   -34.0538   138.1554
41.2669   -33.0179   139.2269
4.7500   -32.7926   138.1523
16.2453   -32.9552   138.2604
5.5949   -32.4923   138.1866
7.9533   -31.8304   138.6966
```

My wrong function (I know I must have a problem with loops but I can't figure out what) so far is:

```
def converted_lines ():
    file_out = open ('receiver.in', 'w')
    converted_lines = []
    event_dict = reloc_event_coords_dic()
    data_line = event_dict.items() # Takes data as('EVENT31933', ['10.1230 -32.8294 138.1718'])
    for element in data_line:
        for item in element:
            event_number = element[0] # Gets event number
            coord_line = event_dict.get (event_number, None)   
    with open ('event_from_picks', 'r') as file_in:
        for line in file_in:
            if line.startswith("  "):
                continue
            if event_number:
                converted_lines.append ("%s" % coord_line)
        file_out.writelines(converted_lines)
```

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

just do the following:

```
with open('receiver.in', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines([v[0] for v in reloc_event_coords_dic().itervalues()])
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, don't know how I managed to read your question so wrong. Fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your first loop just leaves the last pair in the `coord_line` variable.

Better do

```
event_dict = reloc_event_coords_dic()
with open ('event_from_picks', 'r') as file_in:
    with open('receiver.in', 'w') as file_out:
        for in_line in file_in:
            file_out.writelines(event_dict[in_line.strip()])
```

(untested, but you should get the logic).

Comment: @Kimvais none oh them is working. Probably my question is not clear but I just want to replace what I find in 'event_from_picks' (which are keys of my dictionary) with their corresponding values from the same dictionary maintaining the same order as 'event_from_picks'. If something is not clear just let me know...